# Bare minimum plugin won't work on moodle

Tags: moodle

I'm getting myself used to moodle programming. I used [this](http://moodlesensei.blogspot.nl/) guide to make it, but it's from 2010. It might be old, so I'm not sure if it's any good.

This is the error moodle gives me:

- Debug info: Missing mandatory en language pack.
- Error code: detectedbrokenplugin

Stack trace:

- line 634 of \lib\upgradelib.php: plugin_defective_exception thrown
- line 420 of \lib\upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_plugins_modules()
- line 1626 of \lib\upgradelib.php: call to upgrade_plugins()
- line 434 of \admin\index.php: call to upgrade_noncore()

I do have a language pack in my /pluginname/lang/en_US.php.

You can find the plugin [HERE](https://www.dropbox.com/s/p0q91zwr81m7rpt/plugintut.zip?dl=0).

Answer (score 2):

The structure is `/pluginname/lang/en/plugintype_pluginname.php`

The en folder is mandatory which is generally British English.

You can add a US folder too `/pluginname/lang/en_us/plugintype_pluginname.php`

`plugintype` is  mod, block, local, etc.